# Magento 2 Get Customer Data from Order by Email

Tags: php, magento2, magento2.2

I've created an observer for the event: `sales_order_place_after`

I'm able to get customer data from the `customerId`

```
<?php
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Observer\Sales\Order;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Salesrep implements ObserverInterface
{
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
  ){
    $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
  }

  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
   {
     $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
     $customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($order->getCustomerId());

     $salesrep = $customer->getCustomAttribute('salesrep')->getValue();
     $order->setSalesrep($salesrep);
   }
}
```

In the case that the customer orders as a guest, how would I get customer details by email?

I've also tried

`$customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getByEmail($order->getCustomerEmail());`

but that returns an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly after posting this question, I was able to figure it out.

Just needed to change this line

`$customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($order->getCustomerId());`

To

`$customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->get($order->getCustomerEmail(), $websiteId = null);`